# Solutions of PDE

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I am looking for solutions $g \colon \mathbb R^2 \times \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb C$ of the PDE
$$\partial_{x_1} g(x,y) + \partial_{y_1} g(x,y) = a(y_1+x_1+i(x_2-y_2))g(x,y), \\ \partial_{x_2} g(x,y) + \partial_{y_2} g(x,y) = a(y_2+x_2+i(y_1-x_1))g(x,y),$$
where $a>0$ and $(x,y) = (x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2) \in \mathbb R^2 \times \mathbb R^2$. I already know that $f(x,y) := \exp(a(x\cdot y - i x \wedge y))$ with $x\wedge y := x_1 y_2 - x_2 y_1$ is a solution but I was so far not able to find any other (smooth) solution. Does anyone have an answer to this? General approaches to solve this kind of PDE are also appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the system of PDEs strongly decouples, with one equation only dependent on the $(x_{1}, y_{1})$ coordinates while the other is only dependent on the $(x_{2}, y_{2})$ coordinates, it makes sense to solve the problems separately.

For the first PDE, the [method of characteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics) implies (labelling $g \to g_{1}$)

$$\frac{d x_{1}}{1} = \frac{d y_{1}}{1} = \frac{d g_{1}}{a (y_{1} + x_{1} + i (x_{2} - y_{2})) g_{1}}$$

The first equality gives

$$x_{1} - y_{1} = C_{1}$$

Using componendo-divindendo on the first equality and setting it equal to the last ratio gives

\begin{align} 
\frac{d g_{1}}{a (y_{1} + x_{1} + i (x_{2} - y_{2})) g_{1}} &= \frac{d (x_{1} + y_{1})}{2} \\
\implies \frac{dg_{1}}{g_{1}} &= \frac{a (y_{1} + x_{1} + i (x_{2} - y_{2})) d(x_{1} + y_{1})}{2} \\
\implies \ln g_{1} &= \frac{a}{4} (x_{1} + y_{1})^{2} + \frac{i a (x_{2} - y_{2})(x_{1} + y_{1})}{2} + C_{2} \\
\implies g_{1} &= C_{2} \exp \left( \frac{a}{4} (x_{1} + y_{1})^{2} + \frac{i a (x_{2} - y_{2})(x_{1} + y_{1})}{2} \right) \\
&= f_{1}(x_{1} - y_{1}) \exp \left( \frac{a}{4} (x_{1} + y_{1})^{2} + \frac{i a (x_{2} - y_{2})(x_{1} + y_{1})}{2} \right)
\end{align}

which you can check satisfies the first equation. A similar calculation for the second PDE (by symmetry, let $x_{1} \leftrightarrow x_{2}, y_{1} \leftrightarrow y_{2}$ and relabel $g \to g_{2}$) then shows

\begin{align}
\implies g_{2} &= f_{2}(x_{2} - y_{2}) \exp \left( \frac{a}{4} (x_{2} + y_{2})^{2} + \frac{i a (x_{1} - y_{1})(x_{2} + y_{2})}{2} \right)
\end{align}

The final solution is then a superposition of the two

\begin{align}
g = \ &g_{1} + g_{2} \\
= \ &f_{1}(x_{1} - y_{1}) \exp \left( \frac{a}{4} (x_{1} + y_{1})^{2} + \frac{i a (x_{2} - y_{2})(x_{1} + y_{1})}{2} \right) \\
+ \ &f_{2}(x_{2} - y_{2}) \exp \left( \frac{a}{4} (x_{2} + y_{2})^{2} + \frac{i a (x_{1} - y_{1})(x_{2} + y_{2})}{2} \right)
\end{align}

Note that we get the result you found by choosing $f_{1}, f_{2}$ appropriately.

Comment: Thanks! I made a small mistake in the first version of my question, but this should not change your calculation besides replacing $x_1 - y_1$ by $y_1 - x_1$ for $g_2$. $f_1$ and $f_2$ are allowed to be arbitrary, say $C^1$, functions?

Comment: Yes, the $f_{i}$ are arbitrary differentiable functions.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks again.

Comment: Hey, I went through it in more detail now and have two additional questions: The $f_1$ is not allowed to depend on $x_2,y_2$ and on $x_1,x_2$ only through $x_1-x_2$ (and likewise for $f_2$)? How would I choose the $f_i$ to recover my result, this is not obvious to me...

Comment: Sorry, I wrote the answer last night at about 3am and it seems I've omitted the extra coordinates in the $f_{i}$. If I recall it correctly the functions should actually be $f_{1}(x_{1} - y_{1}, x_{2} - y_{2})$ and $f_{2}(x_{1} - y_{1}, x_{2} - y_{2})$ with the $f_{i}$ arbitrary. I'll fix up my post when I get home.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I suspected! Take your time to fix it.

Comment: I suspect that $f_1$ is allowed to depend on $x_1-y_1$ and on $x_2,y_2$, not just the difference of the latter. Otherwise I cannot recover the solution I found.